# How can I write two functions next to each other in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, optimization, python-requests

Hi everyone I have an issue and I just cant't solve it. I provided the output but unfortunately I couldn't get the output that I want.

This is my code and I want my output to look like in the image that I uploaded:

```
    def celiusToFahrenheit():
     print("Celsius\t\t\tFahrenheit")
     for c in reversed(range(31,41)):
        f=(9/5)*c+32
        print(c,"\t\t\t\t",\
              format(f,".1f"))

    def fahrenheitToCelsius():
     print("Fahrenheit\t\t\tCelsius")
     for f in reversed(range(30,130,10)):
        c=(5/9)*(f-32)
        print(f,"\t\t\t\t",\
              format(c,".2f"))
```

The output that I get:

```
C:\Users\emrea\PycharmProjects\helloworld\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/emrea/PycharmProjects/helloworld/app.py
Celsius         Fahrenheit
40               104.0
39               102.2
38               100.4
37               98.6
36               96.8
35               95.0
34               93.2
33               91.4
32               89.6
31               87.8
Celsius         Fahrenheit
40               104.0
39               102.2
38               100.4
37               98.6
36               96.8
35               95.0
34               93.2
33               91.4
32               89.6
31               87.8

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Just like I've said, you can find the output that I want from the link below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/swcx6.png

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asO2H.png)

Comment: Post the full error and traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators would be a good fit for this: Instead of printing inside the functions, `yield` their lines:

```
def celiusToFahrenheit():
    yield "Celsius\t\t\tFahrenheit"
    for c in reversed(range(31, 41)):
        f = (9 / 5) * c + 32
        yield "{}\t\t\t\t{}".format(c, format(f, ".1f"))

def fahrenheitToCelsius():
    yield "Fahrenheit\t\t\tCelsius"
    for f in reversed(range(30, 130, 10)):
        c = (5 / 9) * (f - 32)
        yield "{}\t\t\t\t{}".format(f, format(c, ".1f"))
```

Then you can iterate over both at once:

```
for left, right in zip(celiusToFahrenheit(), fahrenheitToCelsius()):
    print(left, "|", right)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to align the values, you can specify lengths and alignments.
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Adding to @L3viathan's answer above...

```
def celiusToFahrenheit():
    yield "{:^12} {:^12}".format("Celsius", "Fahrenheit")
    yield "-"*25
    for c in reversed(range(31, 41)):
        f = (9 / 5) * c + 32
        yield "{:12} {:>12}".format(c, format(f, ".1f"))


def fahrenheitToCelsius():
    yield "{:^12} {:^12}".format("Fahrenheit", "Celsius")
    yield "-"*25
    for f in reversed(range(30, 130, 10)):
        c = (5 / 9) * (f - 32)
        yield "{:12} {:>12}".format(f, format(c, ".1f"))


for left, right in zip(celiusToFahrenheit(), fahrenheitToCelsius()):
    print(left, "|", right)
```